# How to make the text of a label into the text entered into Entry when a button is clicked?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I meant to ask how to change the text of a label using a function and a button to a text we enter in Entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your problem goes as follows :
suppose your label is 'a' and entry is 'b'

```
def changet():
    a.configure(text=b.get())

root=Tk()
a=Label(root,text='')#initial text is empty
b=Entry(root)
a.pack_forget()
b.pack()
Button(root,text="click here", commmand=changet).pack()
```